# jquery tablesorter How to add class to second td only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tablesorter

I use jquery tablesorter class and I want to add class to second td only on mouseOver event:

<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
</tr>

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#table').mouseover(function() {
   $("#table td:nth-child(2)").addClass("tablesorter");
}
```